# How to access Gmail Atom feed using Zend Libraries (PHP)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I have worked out the oauth authentication etc.

Don't quite know how to access it. Searched the Zend documentation but couldn't find it..

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) for parsing RSS or Atom feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Feed -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html